# SQL Server > reformating a table from rows to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to figure out the right way to do this. Any help is appreciated even just a pointer to a SQL concept I am lacking. I've looked at examples of using `PIVOT` but I am have been at a loss on using the aggregate function needed since I need to retain my values and set them to static named columns.

[image]

Comment: Google sql server PIVOT.

Comment: SQL server 2016+ you might also look into string_agg.